# Determining the underlying type of a generic Type with TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript, generics

Consider the following interface within TypeScript

```
interface IApiCall<TResponse> {
    method: string;
    url: string;
}
```

Which is then used within the following method;

```
const call = <TResponse>(api: IApiCall<TResponse>): void => {
    // call to API via ajax call
    // on response, grab data
    // use JSON.parse(data) to convert to json object
    return json as TResponse;
};
```

Now we use this for Type safety within our methods so we know what objects are being returned from the API. However, when we are returning a single string from the API, `JSON.parse` is converting the string '12345' into a number, which then breaks further down the line when we are trying to treat this as a string and use `value.trim()` yet it has been translated into a number.

So ideas to solve this so that we are not converting a string into a number.

1. How can we stop JSON.parse from converting a single string value into a number?
2. If using JSON.parse, we check the type of `TResponse` and compare it against the typeof of json generated.

```
if (typeof (json) !== typeof(TResponse))...
```

However there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to determine the generic type.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1: How can we stop `JSON.parse()` from converting a single string value into a number?

[JSON](https://www.json.org/) is a text format, so in `JSON.parse(x)`, `x` needs to be a `string`.  But JSON text *represents* data of not-necessarily-`string` types.  It sounds like you might be making a [category mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake), by [confusing a thing with its representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction).

If you convert the number `12345` to JSON (`JSON.stringify(12345)`) you will get the string `"12345"`.  If you parse that string, (`JSON.parse("12345")`), you will get the number `12345` back.  If you wanted to get the string `"12345"`, you need to encode it as JSON ( `JSON.stringify("12345")`) as the string `"\"12345\""`.  If you parse *that* ( `JSON.parse('"12345"'`) you will get the string `"12345"` out.

So the straightforward answer to the question "How can we stop `JSON.parse()` from converting a single string value into a number" is "by properly quoting it".   But maybe the real problem is that you are using `JSON.parse()` on something that isn't really JSON at all.  If you are given the string `"12345"` and want to treat it as the string `"12345"`, then you don't want to do anything at all to it... just use it as-is without calling `JSON.parse()`.

Hope that helps.  If for some reason either of those don't work for you, you should post more details about your use case as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

Question 2: How do we determine that the returned JSON-parsed object matches the generic type?

In TypeScript, the type system exists only at design time and is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) in the emitted JavaScript code that runs later.  So you can't access interfaces and type parameters like `TResponse` at runtime.  The general solution to this is to start with the runtime solution (how would you do this in pure JavaScript) and help the compiler infer proper types at design time.

Furthermore, the interface type `IApiCall`

```
interface IApiCall<TResponse> {
    method: string;
    url: string;
}
```

has no [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) dependence on `TResponse`, which is [not recommended](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--).  So even if we write good runtime code and try to infer types from it, the compiler will never be able to figure out what `TResponse` is.

In this case I'd recommend that you make the `IApiCall` interface include a member which is a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), and then you will have to write your own runtime test for each type you care about.  Like this:

```
interface IApiCall<TResponse> {
  method: string;
  url: string;
  validate: (x: any) => x is TResponse;
}
```

And here's an example of how to create such a thing for a particular `TResponse` type:

```
interface Person {
  name: string,
  age: number;
}
const personApiCall: IApiCall<Person> = {
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://example.com/personGrabber",
  validate(x): x is Person {
    return (typeof x === "object") &&
      ("name" in x) && (typeof x.name === "string") &&
      ("age" in x) && (typeof x.age === "number");
  }
}
```

You can see that `personApiCall.validate(x)` should be a good runtime check for whether or not `x` matches the `Person` interface.  And then, your `call()` function can be implemented something like this:

```
const call = <TResponse>(api: IApiCall<TResponse>): Promise<TResponse | undefined> => {
  return fetch(api.url, { method: api.method }).
    then(r => r.json()).
    then(data => api.validate(data) ? data : undefined);
};
```

Note that `call` returns a `Promise<Person | undefined>` (api calls are probably asynchronous, right?  and the `undefined` is to return something if the validation fails... you can throw an exception instead if you want).  Now you can `call(personApiCall)` and the compiler automatically will understand that the asynchronous result is a `Person | undefined`:

```
async function doPersonStuff() {
  const person = await call(personApiCall); // no <Person> needed here
  if (person) {
    // person is known to be of type Person here
    console.log(person.name);
    console.log(person.age);
  } else {
    // person is known to be of type undefined here
    console.log("File a missing Person report!")
  }
}
```

---

Okay, I hope those answers give you some direction.  Good luck!

Comment: Awesome answer @jcalz thanks for that. Yeah now think that I can actually just skip `JSON.parse` when the value is a string or number, because the `content-type` is `text/plain` rather than `application/json`. Also your solution for getting the type is pretty nice, so will consider that in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Type annotations only exist in TS (`TResponse` will be nowhere within the output JS), you cannot use them as values. You have to use the type of the actual value, here it should be enough to single out the string, e.g.

```
if (typeof json == 'string')
```